# What is the best way to pass redux dispatch to function?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to pass a map dispatch to props function called addNewOrder. The problem is that the function SendSocketData() is going to be using it, not the function listOrders. However in order to access it, i have to drill that prop down. Is there more of a cleaner way to access it without drilling it down?

My thought was to use the useState() hook. I am not sure if that will be correct. Please let me know what is your thoughts on that. Thanks!

```
    function ListOrders ({addNewOrder}) {

   const [socket, setSocket] = useState();
   useEffect(()=> {
      setSocket(io("http://localhost:3001"));
   },[]);
  /*
  * 
  *   Right now im just padding in addNewOrder to the SendSocketDatae
  * 
  * */
   function SendSocketData(socket,addNewOrder) {
 // console.log("hiii");

      socket.emit("new_order", new_order => {
            //console.log(new_order);             
            addNewOrder(new_order);
      });
       socket.on("new_order", new_order => {  
           console.log(new_order)
       });
   }
   return (
       <div className="App">
          <button onClick={()=>SendSocketData(socket)}>Send Data </button>
       </div>
   );
}  
const mapStateToProps = state => {
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return ({
        addNewOrder: (order) => dispatch(addNewOrder(order))
    })
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ListOrders)
```

Comment: I don't see the benefit of keeping the socket in the state. When it comes to the state, it should be something that describes the component UI state. If you need to use it you can use it directly as a constant. Don't mix the patterns. Also, take care of function names which supposed to be used as camelCase.

Comment: Is there any reason of using hooks in your component and not doing the same with redux where you create a dispatch instance using useDispatch from react-redux? And useSelector to get the data/props into the component.